# How to change wishlist icon color, if item is present in database in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

> How I can change the wishlist icon color if the item is present in the database its color is brown If the item is not present in the database its color is black.
>
> And also I will be able to toggle between colors. This means that ( If an item is present in the database its returned color is already changed when I click on the icon its color should be changed and returned black color and the item is removed from the database). When I click again on the icon it should send a request and add the item to the database and returned color is brown again.

**If you haven't understood the problem ask me! and (item returned from the database is correctly fine and its value is stored in [itemPresent] hook)**

```
import React, { useState,useCallback,useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { BsDash, BsPlus } from "react-icons/bs";
import axios from '../../axios-orders';
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner'
import {RiHeart3Fill} from 'react-icons/ri';



const Details = (props) => {
    
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [toggleHeart, setToggleHeart] = useState(false);
    const [itemPresent, setItemPresent] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.post('/UserPortal/CartItems/get_wishlist.php', {
            customer_id: localStorage.getItem('Id')
        } )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
         response.data.map((item)=>{
            return setItemPresent(item.product_id)
        })
    
        if(itemPresent === id){
            console.log('[item]',itemPresent)
        }
        })
    },[toggleHeart,id,itemPresent])


    var c = props.orders.find(product => product.id === id);

    

    const changeColor = useCallback(() =>{
        setToggleHeart(!toggleHeart);
        const data = {
            customer_id: localStorage.getItem('Id'),
            name: c.name,
            price: c.price,
            description: c.description,
            quantity: c.quantity,
            product_id : c.id
        }
        axios.post('/UserPortal/CartItems/wishlist.php', data )
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data);
            })
       },[toggleHeart,c.id,c.name,c.price,c.description,c.quantity])


   if(props.orders.length === 0){
    return <Spinner/>;
   }

 return (
                <div className="details__info">
                              
                                {localStorage.getItem('email') 
                                ? itemPresent ? 

                                 <RiHeart3Fill className={
                                    toggleHeart ? 'heart active' : 'heart'
                                  } onClick={changeColor}/>

                                :   <RiHeart3Fill className="heart" onClick={changeColor}/>
                                :   <RiHeart3Fill className="heart"/>

               }
                                </div>
                      
   
                  );
```

**CSS FILE**

```
.heart{
    font-size: 35px;
    color:rgb(182, 173, 173);
    margin-top: 7px;
     width: 70px;
     outline: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-weight: bold;
     &:hover{
         color: rgb(192, 39, 39);
     }
    &.active {
        color: rgb(192, 39, 39);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define css classes in useState hook and update it once a item is added or removed.

Below is the code suggestion you can try and see if helps you,

```
const [cssClass, setCssClass] = useState("heart")


useEffect(() => 
{
  if(toggleHeart)
  {
    setCssClass("heart active")
  }
  else
  {
    setCssClass("heart")
  }


},[toggleHeart])




 return (
 <div className="details__info">
                              
 {localStorage.getItem('email') 
 ? itemPresent ? 

 <RiHeart3Fill 
  className={cssClasses} 
  onClick={changeColor}
  />

  :   <RiHeart3Fill className="heart" onClick={changeColor}/>
  :   <RiHeart3Fill className="heart"/>

  }
  </div>
                      
   
 );
```

Comment: How i can deal it with database. like when item is present in database its color changed and when removed its color changed. And also i am able to click on icon and when unselect its color is changed in their default state.

Comment: You have to manage global state in such cases, like Redux / useContext.

And when you fetch data from database, you can manage in Redux store and then dispatch some actions to manage the color of item based on the data on the store.

To accomplish this, you have to have a good understanding on how Redux works.